# What should be the verb in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

> As the guest accesses previously
> untouched regions of its virtual address space, hardware page faults
> vector control to the VMM.

I have difficulties understanding which one should be the verb of this sentence. Since I saw the "to" follows "control" so I think it's certainly not a verb. Which one should be the verb and why the author using it here.

Comment: Don't you think the sentence is somewhat 'technical'? Is it some kind of computer blurb? Anyway, the matrix (main) verb appears to be "accesses", and the verb in the subordinate clause appears to be "vector".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two clauses in that sentence,
a subordinate one:
As the guest **accesses** previously untouched regions of its virtual address space,
and a main one:
hardware page faults **vector** control to the VMM.

I've highlighted the verb in each clause.

(*vector* is an unusual verb, probably limited to programming, meaning to redirect control to another part of a program.)